# Android notification icon in code

Tags: android, icons, notifications

When I successfully install an app from android market it show success icon in notification.
How can I get it in code ?
Ex :

```
Notification notification = new Notification(
        android.R.drawable.stat_notify_sdcard, "", System.currentTimeMillis());
```

`android.R.drawable.stat_notify_sdcard` is sdcard icon . So what is install success icon ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the install success icon, but it is close to it.

```
android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download_done
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this ?

```
 android.R.drawable.ic_notification_overlay,
android.R.drawable.ic_notification_clear_all
```

Comment: No . It's not install success icon .